# How do I successfully install the package "mordecai", given the installation guide?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install the package `mordecai`. The installation guide is here:https://github.com/openeventdata/mordecai

I tried installing it using the terminal in VS Code via the command `pip install mordecai`, which resulted in a long error that ends with this:

```
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
        Running setup.py clean for blis
      Failed to build thinc preshed blis
      Installing collected packages: wrapt, wasabi, plac, cymem, wheel, tqdm, srsly, six, setuptools, preshed, numpy, murmurhash, Cython, thinc_gpu_ops, blis, thinc
        Running setup.py install for preshed: started
        Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Running setup.py install for preshed did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [13 lines of output]
            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              warnings.warn(
            running install
            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
              warnings.warn(
            running build
            running build_py
            running build_ext
            building 'preshed.maps' extension
            clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c preshed/maps.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/preshed/maps.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
            clang: error: no such file or directory: 'preshed/maps.cpp'
            clang: error: no input files
            error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> preshed
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I thought that these questions might have an answer, but they have not been able to answer my question.

[How can I install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-can-i-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from)

[How to install PIL with pip on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/how-to-install-pil-with-pip-on-mac-os)

[How to update/upgrade a package using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071256/how-to-update-upgrade-a-package-using-pip)

[How do I install pandas into visual studios code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946868/how-do-i-install-pandas-into-visual-studios-code)

I looked through many questions on this site, but cannot seem to find an answer as to what I can do to install this package.

I have also tried the following, which produces the same error message:

```
python3 -m venv mordecai-env
source mordecai-env/bin/activate
pip3 install mordecai
```

***Please let me know if I can make my attempts or the question more clear, or if any other information is needed.***

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: I have just added the full error message @SuperStormer

Comment: It is a dreadful installation process, I finally got it running on [google colab](https://gist.github.com/rjadr/8967effee72795dd0d9792073a9b4cd5).

Comment: I decided to use GeoText instead, the installation process was far easier and it works great.

Comment: Indeed, I just moved to [this](https://pypi.org/project/local-geocode/) module, it's also quite fast.